# Failing to create a std::ranges::iota_view with value and bound

Tags: c++, range

I tried to create a [std::ranges::iota_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) with a value and a bound:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector v{1,2,3};
  auto indices = std::ranges::views::iota(0, v.size());
}
```

[link to program on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eEffvn)

But clang 11.0.0 fails to compile with the error message:

> no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'iota_view'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view

> Note that the [deduction] guide protects itself against signed/unsigned mismatch bugs, like `views::iota(0, v.size())`, where `0` is a (signed) int and `v.size()` is an (unsigned) std::size_t.

This will work:

```
auto indices = std::ranges::views::iota(0u, v.size());
                                         ^ unsigned zero literal
```

Unfortunately Clang seems to have another bug, but it [works in gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/qr5hGb); or you can [use range-v3](https://godbolt.org/z/93nasz).

Comment: Great thanks! How could I miss it ^^ With the ranges-v3 library it works: https://godbolt.org/z/7vv3f5

Comment: Haha ^^ you were faster with the range-v3 version. Thanks!